# Are questions about "no-SQL" databases OK?

Tags: discussion, faq, allowed-questions

Is it appropriate to ask questions about things like [Redis](http://redis.io) (a data-structure server)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, so long as they are expert level (or at least, not beginner stuff, please).

The premise of this site is that it is for professionals -- or people who *want to be professionals* -- who are very experienced with databases.

Comment: If this site is for professionals and not "beginner stuff" where should beginners be going to get help again?

Comment: @melton "or people who *want to be profesionals*" per above

Answer (score 16):

Yes. No-SQL databases are encouraged here. The intent of the site is for all non-filesystem data storage analysis, more or less. If it's memcachedb or Oracle 11G, we want to talk about it here.

We only ask that you keep things objective, of course.